# Support for Horizontal scaling with quarkus & Jberet using the quarkus-jberet extenstion

Tags: quarkus, batch-processing

I am used to quarkus as a whole and exploring quarkus Jberet. I want to figure out how to run quarkus with quarkus-jberet extension and scale the app in kubernetes for batch processing? I know I can go with a kuberentes Job type app with an executable, but wondering if I can use Jbatch and its features in k8 environemnt with the horizontal scaling?

On trying out a simple app with quarkus with jberet extension I realised it creates a long running quarkus application like a web container but you can also hold job container which can trigger jobs as and when needed.  I am wondering how do you use this to horizontally scale the app so the load can be shared by more than one pod in a kubernetes environment for running the same Job.

I have tried to quarkus 2.16 with jberet 1.21. As we need some more time to come to the latest version of quarkus & hence quarkus-Jberet extension. But appreciate if we have a solution in highe r version as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up a shared JobRepository (for instance, with JDBC), and then start / stop each job using REST endpoints (also provided by the jberet-rest module). With a load balancer, each job execution could be spread across your pods.

Alternatively you could set up a Quarkus main class, which takes the job to run, so you don't have a long-running process.